# Retrieving Phone Number from Android Contacts Doesn't Work On Samsung

Tags: android, android-contacts, phone-number

When I put the code in starting from the line `"// Using the contact ID now we will get contact phone number"` to the line `"cursorPhone.close"`, it doesn't display any contact info on my s3 or note 3, but does display it on my asus tablet. If i take out the code between the lines mentioned above, the code works on s3 and note 3. What am i doing wrong? There are no errors in the log.

```
private void getContacts() {

    try {

        String[] projection = new String[] {
                ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
                ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER,
                ContactsContract.Contacts._ID };

        mCursor = managedQuery(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
                projection, ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + "=?", new String[] { "1" },
                ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME);

            String phoneNumber = '';
        while (mCursor.moveToNext()) {
            contact contact = new contact();

            String contactId = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
            contact.setContactName(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME)));

    // Using the contact ID now we will get contact phone number
            Cursor cursorPhone = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                    new String[]{ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER},

                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ? AND " +
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE + " = " +
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE,

                    new String[]{contactId},
                    null);

            if (cursorPhone.moveToFirst()) {
                phoneNumber = (cursorPhone.getString(cursorPhone.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER)));
            }

            cursorPhone.close();//till here             




            contact_list.add(contact);
        }
        isChecked = new boolean[mCursor.getCount()];

        for (int i = 0; i < isChecked.length; i++) {
            isChecked[i] = false;
        }

        this.mContactAdapter = new contactAdapter(this, R.layout.contactlistview, contact_list);
        lv.setAdapter(this.mContactAdapter);
        mCursor.close();

        runOnUiThread(returnRes);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("getContacts", e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

why dont you try to open inbuild Contact activity using -

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
        android.provider.ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI);

startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT); Hope this helps you.
```

You need to handle code In Activity Result Method of Activty like this:

```
    if (reqCode == PICK_CONTACT && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

            //  final String phoneNumber = data.getStringExtra("android.intent.extra.PHONE_NUMBER");

                if (data != null) {
                    Uri uri = data.getData();

                    if (uri != null) {
                        Cursor c = null;
                        try {
                            c = getContentResolver().query(uri, new String[]{ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER},
                                    null, null, null);

                            if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
                                String number = c.getString(0); 
                                number=number.replaceAll("\\s", "");
                                number=number.replaceAll("-", "");
                                edtPhoneNumber.setText(number);
                            }
                        } finally {
                            if (c != null) {
                                c.close();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }


                finishActivity(PICK_CONTACT);
            }
            if (reqCode == PICK_CALLLOG && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                edtPhoneNumber.setText(data.getStringExtra("CallerNumber"));

            }
            if (reqCode == PICK_SMSLOG && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                edtPhoneNumber.setText(data.getStringExtra("CallerNumber"));
            }
}
```

Comment: 1. Because I'm building a custom list view
2. also building the ability to select multiple contacts at once.